# Sort included resource by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I look for all my contacts and include the related notes by using this (which works fine):

```
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id], :include => :notes)
```

However, I want to sort the included notes by the created_at date, how can I achieve this?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Did you try just adding `:order => :created_at` to the `has_many :notes` line in the Contact model, or would this break something else for you?

Comment: Thanks, I used "has_many :notes, :order => 'created_at DESC'" and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Either add the `:order` clause to your `has_many` declaration as Martin suggested, or add it to the query, where you'll probably have to specify the table name to avoid ambiguities. In Rails 3.x syntax:

```
 Contact.includes(:notes).find(params[:id]).order("notes.created_at DESC")
```

Comment: I don't believe that will work... `Contact.find(id)` will be a Contact object, not a Relation, so it doesn't have an includes method, or if it does, it won't do what you want. Using `Contact.where(:id => params(:id)` instead of Contact.find won't fail, but I don't know that you can sort the included objects that way.

Comment: I believe it'll still fail as long as .find comes before .order, since Contact doesn't have an 'order' method any more than it does 'includes'.